# User Locked out after 5 failed login attempts - how to help him?

Tags: 8, users

I have a user with 5 failed login attempts...and now he's locked out. We reset his password...but is there something else we need to do to unlock his account on a basic Drupal 8 setup?

I'd rather not have to get into using drush on this remote server and messing around with db tables...especially since this is just one user out of thousands. I just want a simple UI solution.

Or does he have to wait 6 hours or something crazy?

Comment: I know in D7 you just need to clear the Flood table from your DB, [see this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440). Might be the same for D8.

Comment: Is it this issue? https://www.drupal.org/node/992540

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [flood_unblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_unblock) module you can just flush the flood for the specific user or ip.

Comment: Interesting...I may try this, thank you. I was hoping for some quick solution that didn't involve adding a module, but this may be the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's a default config for flood settings in `core/modules/user/config/install/user.flood.yml`:

```
uid_only: false
ip_limit: 50
ip_window: 3600
user_limit: 5
user_window: 21600
```

This means, that your user is locked for 21600 secs by default. Be patient :-)
Unfortunately, there's no UI for that config currently. A workaround would be to import a single config in the Config-Sync UI.

All flood info is stored in table "flood". It's save to delete * from flood to reset all floodings. A flood info is by default ip-based like "uid-ip". So, if your user can change his client IP, she may be able to login before 21600 secs have passed.